# Cant resolve infinite recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, treeview

Ive recently started coding on populating a treeview control from a list and this is where i am starting.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/11/09/populating-a-treeview-control-from-a-list.aspx

I am currently trying to retrieve registry paths and storing them to a list. From that list, I am trying to add it as parent nodes to the treeview control. Then I traverse every level in the registry and add them as nodes eventually creating a tree-like replica of it. I am retrieving registry information through a separate process and I shy away from using the Registry API within c#. I incorporated all of the code in the link above to my current code and now i am experiencing an infinite recursion error everytime i compile.

This is the current code I am working on.

```
private void registry()
{
    string hivelist_output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string[] hivelist_lines = Regex.Split(hivelist_output, "\r\n");
    string[] registry_paths = new string[hivelist_lines.Length];
    List<string> registry_path_list = new List<string>();

    for (i = 0; i < hivelist_lines.Length; i++)
    {
        registry_paths[i] = hivelist_lines[i].Substring(22);
        registry_path_list.Add(registry_paths[i].Trim());
    }
    for (i = 0; i < registry_path_list.Count; i++)
    {
        treeViewList.Add(new TreeViewItem()
        {
            ParentID = 0,
            ID = i,
            Text = registry_path_list[i]
        });
    }
    PopulateTreeView(0, null);
    treeView1.ExpandAll();
}
private void PopulateTreeView(int parentId, TreeNode parentNode)
{
    var filteredItems = treeViewList.Where(item => item.ParentID == parentId);

    TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode();

    foreach (var i in filteredItems.ToList())
    {
        if (parentNode == null)
            childNode = treeView1.Nodes.Add(i.Text);
        else
            childNode = parentNode.Nodes.Add(i.Text);

        PopulateTreeView(i.ID, childNode);
    }
}
```

The error of infinite recursion points me to this line of code and I dont understand why.

```
childNode = parentNode.Nodes.Add(i.Text);
```

I appreciate your great advice on this matter. Thanks in advance!

-------------------------------------SOLVED-------------------------------------------

Moving forward, now my next problem is to add the subkeys below each parent node (registry path) and as well as the subkeys below each of the previously retrieved subkeys and key values and data types. Since the registry is quite deep, how could i make it so that I plot all possible values without using too much nested loops? Thanks!

*structure of what I would like to achieve

```
registry path
    - subkey1
        - subkeys of subkey1
            - subkeys of subkey1.1
            - data types & values
    -subkey 2
        .
        .
        .
    -subkey 3
    .
    .
    .
    -subkey n
    - data types & values
```

so and so forth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding TreeViewItems *always* with ID = 0. Therefore, your PopulateTreeView always calls itself recursively with ID 0.

You need to fix your setup method:

```
for (i = 0; i < registry_path_list.Count; i++)
{
    treeViewList.Add(new TreeViewItem()
    {
        ParentID = 0,
        ID = 0,
        Text = registry_path_list[i]
    });
}
```

and use the corresponding IDs.

Comment: my bad i miscopied my code. I already edited my code and it should be ID = i.

Comment: The same applies to your ParentID. If you set ParentID = i, you have a similar problem. This would mean that a TreeViewItem is *its own* Parent, which will cause your recursion.

Comment: Based on my understanding, if i have the same ParentID of 0 they would all be the first level of nodes, which I intend to do. I was trying to do it in small progresses wherein I would first plot the first levels then the their childs and so on and so forth. How do I fix this and how do I go from here? Thanks!

Comment: Take a step back and look again at your code. Your for-loop creates as first element a TreeViewItem with i = 0. Therefor, the ID *and* the ParentID is 0. Then, you're triggering `PopulateTreeView` with parentId=0. This will (among others) find your element with the ID 0 itself. At the very end of your `PopulateTreeView`, you call `PopulateTreeView` again, with `i.ID`, which is 0 *again*. The whole process starts over and over again. You *cannot* have an element where ParentID == ID.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem of infinite recursion by making so that ParentID and ID do not have the same values, which you have said. I fixed it by assigning ID a value higher that ParentID which is ID = i + 1. It may not be a long term/definite solution but temporarily it is , I guess.

Comment: This should be your long term solution as an element cannot be its own parent. ID's should be unique and the hierarchy should not contain loops.